# What is the proper way to add a Trigger to a Oracle11g Database using Jdevelopper 12.1

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

For a Database class, we have to initiate a bunch of SQL triggers using a Oracle 11g Database in a VM (Virtual Machine).

Problem is, even if we're 99% sure our triggers are properly made, we can't seem to find where to add the triggers from Jdev to our database.

What would be the proper way to insert a trigger in the DB?

Thanks!

Comment: Run the approriate `CREATE TRIGGER ..` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use DDL with JDBC. The statement to execute is `CREATE TRIGGER ..`

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I can run another script that will insert the triggers contained in my .trg?

Comment: yes, but if you are using Jdeveloper then you can do it in Java.

Comment: Google is your friend.